# Ignore case from user input

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

I'm trying to write a script to catch user input. The script should ignore the case.

Consider this script `foo.sh`:

```
if [ $1 == "string" ]; then
  echo true
else
  echo false
fi
```

If the input of `foo.sh`is `STRING` or `StRiNg` the result is going to be false.

How can I ignore the case in the `if` condition?

Comment: You should use `[[ "$1" == "string" ]]` instead of `[ $1 == "string" ]`. Otherwise you will get into trouble, if `$1` contains spaces or is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using `bash 4.0+`:

```
${1,,}
```

Otherwise, `tr` or `awk` should work:

```
var=$(echo "$1" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')
var=$(echo "$1" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
```

Summaries:

- Awk takes in the input and simply prints `$0` (the whole input line) after using the built in `tolower()` function.
- Tr looks pretty self explanatory, but let me know if you have questions on it.

Comment: better to quote `"$a"`

Answer (score 1):

`declare` has a lower-case function:

```
declare -l str=$1
[[ $str = "string" ]] && echo true || echo false
```

Comment: There's also the `nocasematch` shell option that could be used.